# Como leer el atributo lastModified de un archivo que esta hospedado on-line en el mismo servidor

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy haciendo mis primeros pasos con JavaScript y por lo tanto desde ya pido disculpas si mi pregunta es muy básica o no hace sentido.

El código a seguir registra en la consola el contenido de un archivo (myfile.txt) que se encuentra hospedado on-line en el mismo servidor y folder donde se encuentra hospedada la pagina conteniendo dicho código. Todo ocurre sin intervención humana, automaticamente al cargar la pagina.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

async function doIt()
{
  let response = await fetch("myfile.txt", {cache: "no-store"});
  let contents = await response.text();
  console.log(contents);
}
    doIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

En lugar de leer el contenido del archivo myfile.txt yo preciso leer solamente la fecha/hora en que dicho archivo fue modificado por ultima vez (atributo lastModified) y hasta ahora no he podido lograrlo.

Que alteración tendría que hacer en el código abajo para obtener el resultado deseado?

Agradezco anticipadamente cualquier ayuda u orientación!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de otro usuario (en la [versión en Inglés de Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) ya tengo la solución que estaba buscando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

async function doIt()
{

  var lastMod = null;
  await fetch("myfile.txt", {cache: "no-store"}).then(r => {
    lastMod = r.headers.get('Last-Modified');
    console.log(lastMod);
})
}
    doIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```